# Angular 6: Create dynamic reactive form but got an Error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently creating an Accordion with Reactive Form with Angular 6. I am also using the Accordion module from primeNG.

Based on the object(cuList), The FormControl(input boxes) will be dynamically created. I created a FormGroup and dynamically added group with FormBuilder. However, I got this error in run time:
[image: error message from console] (Please see the error message below, if the link doesn't work)

```
ERROR Error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
   Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});"
```

and `ERROR TypeError: "this.form is undefined"` 3 times.

I tried some methods according to some of the stackoverflow answers. It didn't solve my problem.

I simplified my code just for readability.

Component HTML

```
<p-accordion #accordion [hidden]="!cuList" [multiple]="true">
    <form *ngIf="cuList" [formGroup]="reportForm" role="form">
        <p-accordionTab header="{{ cu.code }} - {{ cu.name }}" *ngFor='let cu of cuList; let counter = index' [selected]="counter===0">               
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control"
                    name="wages"
                    placeholder=""
                    formControlName="wages_{{ counter }}"
                    currencyMask
                    [(ngModel)]="cu.wage"
                    [options]="{ prefix: '$ ', thousands: ',', allowNegative: false, precision: 0}"
                    maxlength="15"
                    required />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>                      
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control"
                    name="payments"
                    placeholder=""
                    formControlName="subkPay_{{ counter }}"
                    currencyMask
                    [(ngModel)]="cu.subcontractorPayment"
                    [options]="{ prefix: '$ ', thousands: ',', allowNegative: false, precision: 0}"
                    maxlength="15"
                    required />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control"
                    name="excessPayroll"
                    currencyMask
                    formControlName="exsPay_{{ counter }}"
                    [(ngModel)]="cu.excessPayroll"
                    [options]="{ prefix: '$ ', thousands: ',', allowNegative: false, precision: 0}"
                    maxlength="15"
                    required />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p-accordionTab>
    </form>
</p-accordion>
```

Component ts

```
export class EmployerCuListComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('accordion') accordion: Accordion;
    reportForm: FormGroup;   // form
    cuList: EmployerCu[];

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._employercuService.getEmployerCu().subscribe(data => {
            this.cuList = data;
        });
        if (this.cuList) {
            this.createForm(this.cuList);
        }
    }

    createForm(cuList: EmployerCu[]) {
        const group = {};

        cuList.forEach((cu, index) => {
            group['wages_' + index] = ['', [Validators.required]];
            group['subkPay_' + index] = ['', [Validators.required]];
            group['exsPay_' + index] = ['', [Validators.required]];
        });
        this.reportForm = this._fb.group(group); // create form with FormBuilder
    }
}
```

I am assuming it is a timing issue? and the page loaded before the object is initialize?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you call this inside constructor instead of ngOnInit

Comment: @VithuBati, it is bad Angular practice to do such things inside a constructor. A component constructor should handle nothing more than creating the class while things like retrieving data should be handled once the component has been initialised i.e. `OnInit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a timing issue, and I think I know the fix..
Change:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._employercuService.getEmployerCu().subscribe(data => {
        this.cuList = data;
    });
    if (this.cuList) {
        this.createForm(this.cuList);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this._employercuService.getEmployerCu().subscribe(data => {
        this.cuList = data;
        if (this.cuList) {
            this.createForm(this.cuList);
        }
    });
}
```

I believe that without that change the if statement is always hit before this.cuList is set and therefore this.createForm is never called.

this is due to the async nature of the .subscribe() method.

also fyi:
you can verify this but putting a

debugger;

statement at the top of your ngOnInit(), if you do that you should be able to step thru your code in the browser's dev console.

Comment: Very nice. This solved my problem. And yes, it is the asynchronous nature of the subscribe method. Thank you for bringing this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is pretty nice and should fix the problem.